# Error while indexing in solr data crawled by nutch

Tags: solr, indexing, runtime-error, nutch

I have starting working with nutch and solr and I have a problem with integrating Solr with Nutch. I followed this tutorial: http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial and after using:
`bin/nutch crawl urls -solr http://localhost:8983/solr/ -depth 3 -topN 5`
nutch shows message:

> java.io.IOException: Job failed!

and solr is showing:

> SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR:
>   [doc=http://nutch.apache.org/] unknown field 'host'

I thought that the reason might be a missing 'host' field in the $SOLR_HOME/example/solr/conf/schema.xml but it is there.
I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Did you copy the Nutch schema to SOLR? cp ${NUTCH_RUNTIME_HOME}/conf/schema.xml ${APACHE_SOLR_HOME}/example/solr/conf/

Comment: Check if host is defined in schema. Stop Solr. Remove data directory. Start Solr. Try again.

Comment: Ok, I had to define this field in ${APACHE_SOLR_HOME}/example/solr/collection1/conf and now is working. Thanks for help.

Comment: Please add answers as Answers, and mark this question "Answered".

Answer (score 2):

Changing configuration at Nutch side does not effect the schema of Solr. You have to define that field at schema.xml of Solr.